# C++ Boost - serialization error - passing ‘const B’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'm trying to to serialize a simple class using `Boost`. My class contains only one `std::vector`, as can be seen in the code below. My problem is, that while I proceeded according to [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#splitting), I'm getting the error described below. I have no idea why, as I'm not defining `const` anywhere. Do you know, what am I doing wrong?

---

#### My code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

class B {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

private:
    std::vector<int>* v;

protected:
    template<class Archive>
    void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version){
        ar & this->v->size();
        for(int i = 0; i < this->v->size(); i++) {
            ar & this->v->at(i);
        }
    };

    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
        size_t size;
        int tmp;
        ar & size;

        this->v = new std::vector<int>(size);
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            ar & tmp;
            this->v->at(i) = tmp;
        }
    }

    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()

public:
    B();
    B(std::vector<int>* v);
    void print_vals();
};

B::B() {
    this->v = nullptr;
}

B::B(std::vector<int>* v) {
    this->v = v;
}

void B::print_vals() {
    for(auto e : *(this->v)) {
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};

    B b(&v);

    std::ofstream ofs("b.txt");
    {
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << b;
        ofs.close();
    }
}
```

---

#### ERROR

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp:37,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:39,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_oarchive.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_oarchive.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/basic_text_oarchive.hpp:29,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp:31,
                 from /home/martin/CLionProjects/boost_serialization_example/main.cpp:4:
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::serialization::access::member_save(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive; T = const B]’:
/usr/include/boost/serialization/split_member.hpp:43:32:   required from ‘static void boost::serialization::detail::member_saver<Archive, T>::invoke(Archive&, const T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive; T = B]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/split_member.hpp:69:18:   required from ‘void boost::serialization::split_member(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive; T = B]’
/home/martin/CLionProjects/boost_serialization_example/main.cpp:35:5:   required from ‘void B::serialize(Archive&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:116:9:   required from ‘static void boost::serialization::access::serialize(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive; T = B]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:68:22:   required from ‘void boost::serialization::serialize(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive; T = B]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:126:14:   [ skipping 4 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:310:22:   required from ‘static void boost::archive::detail::save_non_pointer_type<Archive>::invoke(Archive&, const T&) [with T = B; Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/oserializer.hpp:534:18:   required from ‘void boost::archive::save(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive; T = const B]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_oarchive.hpp:70:22:   required from ‘void boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<Archive>::save_override(T&) [with T = const B; Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/basic_text_oarchive.hpp:83:9:   required from ‘void boost::archive::basic_text_oarchive<Archive>::save_override(T&) [with T = const B; Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_oarchive.hpp:70:9:   required from ‘Archive& boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<Archive>::operator<<(const T&) [with T = B; Archive = boost::archive::text_oarchive]’
/home/martin/CLionProjects/boost_serialization_example/main.cpp:107:15:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:91:9: error: passing ‘const B’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
         t.save(ar, file_version);
```

---

#### Edit 1:

I've rewritten my `save` and `load` functions according to the answer, but the error persists...

```
template<class Archive>
void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version){
    ar & this->v->size();
    for(int i = 0; i < this->v->size(); i++) {
        ar & (*this->v)[i];
    }
};

template<class Archive>
void load(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) {
    size_t size;
    int tmp;
    ar & size;

    this->v = new std::vector<int>(size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ar & tmp;
        (*this->v)[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The solution:**

Your `save()` method needs to be declared `const` like this:

```
void save(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version) const {
...
```

This will make it compile without errors. If in addition you want complete warning-free compilation then also fix the `for` loop inside `save()` to be like this (changing type of `i` from `int` to `size_t`):

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < this->v->size(); i++)
```

**Explanation:**

> I have no idea why, as I'm not defining const anywhere. Do you know,
>   what am I doing wrong?

So the problem is not that you're *not* defining const, but rather that you're not defining it enough. See, when you call

```
oa << b;
```

then the instantiated version of operator `<<` of class `boost::archive::text_oarchive` has the following signature:

```
'Archive &boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<Archive>::operator <<<B>(const T &)'
```

Hence, it expects to get a `const T&`. But then, it would settle for a regular `T&` because non-`const` is accepted when expecting a `const` argument. But then it tries to use it as a const to no avail because the method upon which it invokes is not at all defined `const` and so your trustworthy compiler was wise enough to stop you right there and then : )

Comment: Thank you! But I guess, that only `save` method is supposed to be `const`, as `load` being `const` make it impossible to initialize properties of the object being loaded.

Comment: @Eenoku Of course 100%, granted and corrected. I wrote in haste as my mind wandered. My apologies. Anyways now the answer is complete. Hope it helped.